# Can't get awesome_print gem to work

Tags: ruby, rubygems, awesomeprint

[awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) looks like a pretty nice gem, so I wanted to try it out.

I went to one of my projects and did:

```
gem install awesome_print
```

and it says one gem installed, documentation installed, etc.

Then, while I am in that project, I went to my Rails console to try it out, but when I did a `require "awesome_print"` as their help file says, I get a "cannot load such file".

Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: you need to add it to your Gemfile

Comment: so "adding to gem file"  is still needed although we do a gem install?

Comment: No, you don't _need_ to add it to your Gemfile. The [selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017892/199712) shows a way to use awesome_print without adding it to your Gemfile. I personally don't want to add awesome_print to my Gemfile because a) I want to be able to take advantage of awesome_print for any Ruby project on my system and b) I don't want to add a gem to a particular project's Gemfile that's only relevant to my personal preferences and not actually a requirement for the project to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`gem install` will put the gem code on your computer, but unless the gem's source code files are on your load path, `require` won't be able to find them.  `bundle exec` looks at the nearest `Gemfile.lock` and adds the source code for all the gems listed there to your load path.  Rails initialization includes getting Bundler to do this for you.

One solution is to add `awesome_print` to your `Gemfile`.  However, this will cause your application to have `awesome_print` as a dependency.  Alternatively you can manually add the `awesome_print` library to your load path after starting up the Rails console and then requiring it:

```
$ rails c
> $LOAD_PATH << path/to/awesome_print-x.x.x/lib
> require 'awesome_print'
> ap {foo: {bar: {baz: :qux}}}
```

If you're using RVM, the path is likely to be something like:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-x.x.x-pxxx@your_gemset_name/gems/awesome_print-x.x.x/lib
```

Comment: awesome_print doesn't work if you do `C:\> app` or `C:\> app.request`, `C:\> app.response` and others. It doesn't affect method calls.

Comment: I absolutely have awesome_print in my Gemfile and it installs just fine, but I get the same error as the original OP when I try to require it inside a file.

Comment: should the load path be in quotes?

Answer (score 27):

Add it to your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
```

I add it to the development group, since that's the only time I need it. The gem doesn't have any other gem dependencies, so I routinely add it to my Gemfile.

Also, add these two lines to your ~/.irbrc file to set `ap` to be your default pager:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

Note that if you use this, however, any projects where awesome_print is not installed in its Gemfile will raise this error when you run `rails c`:

```
cannot load such file -- awesome_print
```

Depending on whatever else you may have in your ~/.irbrc file, this can cause other side effects, such as messing up your prompt. To avoid these, simply add the two lines to the very end of that file.

Answer (score 6):

## install it :

```
$ gem install awesome_print
```

## include it in you GemFile, if you want :

```
gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
```

## add this line to the file ~/.irbrc :

```
require 'awesome_print'
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

## restart your shell!

just a note: I did this and it didnt work right away, probably need to restart the computer... or I just needed to close all shell tabs and open the terminal again!

Answer (score 5):

Install the gem on your machine

```
gem install awesome_print
```

Get the path to which it has installed

```
gem which awesome_print
```

Add the following configuration to your `~/.irbrc`or `~/.pryrc` or `~/.rdbgrc`. This will load Awesome Print whenever you fire an `IRB` or a `pry` session.

*Remember `$LOAD_PATH` will hold whatever you got from typing `gem which awesome_print`

*Edit:* Adding `; nil` to the `$LOAD_PATH` line will prevent its contents from being printed out every time the file is executed.

```
# ~/.irbc or ~/.pryrc or ~/.rdbgrc

$LOAD_PATH << "~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/"; nil
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

Comment: I can ```gem install awesome_print```. I can ```require``` it from irb. But I cannot ```require``` it from my scripts! It was working just a few days ago! And right after installation, ```gem which awesome_print``` fails with "ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library awesome_print".

Comment: This approach worked nicely for me, but the entire $LOAD_PATH was printed out every time I opened my Rails console. Adding `; nil` to the end fixed it for me.
Ex. `$LOAD_PATH << "path_to_gem"; nil`

Comment: @RocketAppliances can you edit my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to install it without having it in your Gemfile, this is how to do it:

```
$ gem install awesome_print
```

I was running into an issue where it was installing successfully but it not in the right directory.

In that case just put this in your .bashrc, this will set the load path:

```
export PATH="/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:$PATH"
PATH="`ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'`/bin:$PATH"
```

replace **2.3.0** with the version of ruby you are working with.
replace **user** with your *username* or if you are using vagrant then replace with *vagrant*

reload your .bashrc or exit the Terminal to reload changes, then install the gem again.

Comment: Looked hopeful, but I have nothing in ```~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0``` except a ```cache``` directory, and it doesn't have awesome_print in it.

Comment: Make sure you check your ruby version with `ruby -v`. Also, I've been using `pry` , `gem install pry` for syntax highlight instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I struggled with PATHs and such, while missing something obvious!

```
# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
# ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
# locate bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/bin/ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
# /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin17]
#
```

Aha! Version crud. I was running an old ruby. Thanks, Apple!

```
# sudo mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby_2.3.7
# sudo ln /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Solved the problem!

There is probably something I could have told `brew` to do to fix things, but I was impatient. :-)